# Is it possible to inline the contents of a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I'd like to use git submodules to track subprojects. I'd also like to have the subprojects' code directly contained in the parent repo, for convenience. Is it possible to inline a submodule such that the parent repo contains a snapshot of the child repo's content at the submodule's commit?

Comment: Not with submodules. Try [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt).

Comment: Please, describe better how you would he project tree be.

Comment: Git subtree looks perfect, thank you! If you post an answer suggesting git subtree I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with submodules. Submodules are always separate repositories.

Try [`git subtree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt). It allows exactly that — to inline a repository inside another. Then you can decide if want to push changed files back to the source repository.